# S3 upload from console failing using Brave browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chromium, brave

I am seeing some console upload to S3 problems, which seem very strange to me.  I am logged in to AWS console with admin access. I have a private S3 bucket (created some months ago with same user & role) with no CORS configuration, no bucket policy, no encryption and permissions which give account owner full control. If I try to upload files to S3 the console always shows me error. But upload hasn't necessarily failed.

For small files (say 15KB), the upload actually succeeds even though console says error. For large files (say 20MB), upload always fails.

I check browser logs and this is the only error I see.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError</Code> 
<Message>The server side encryption configuration was not found</Message> 
<BucketName>apicfn</BucketName><RequestId>6EB2D9BF3FCE9D81</RequestId>
<HostId>sIXpLQO+2w=</HostId></Error>
```

If I try the same (`s3 cp`) from the CLI, it succeeds (S3FullAccess to CLI user).

I am thinking it might be something to do with my browser, but what exactly, I don't know. I am using `Brave` browser `Version 0.60.47 Chromium: 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Any insights?

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Yes, works with Chrome. Was trying to find what exactly does not work.

Comment: Does this issue still exist?

Comment: Check you don't have enabled any CORS extension (like CORS Unblock). In my case, disabling it, solved this issue